# How to test a yes/no outcome with different inputs?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I have what I think is a very simple beginner question, but I do not have any formal training or knowledge of statistics or design of experiments.

Let's say I have a yes,no (0,1) outcome of an experiment, say whether or not a customer purchased a product given a coupon.  There are 5 kinds of coupons, each with different colors, or text, i.e. we want to find the most effective coupon.  Say we collect this data:

```
coupon sample-size yes-count 
     1        2589       153
     2        1789       212
     3        3097       298
     4        2654       281
     5        2103       211
```

What is the right / best way to go about telling which is the best coupon?  As a follow up what if I have two dimensional inputs, say coupon and store-type where store-type can be one of 3 different values.

```
coupon  store-type  sample-size yes-count
     1           1          387        48
     1           2          675       117
     1           3          467        88
 ...
```

Then what would be the best / right way to say which combination of coupon and store-type is most effective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your dependent variable is binary (yes/no), a good starting place at least is logistic regression with coupon-type as a categorical independent variable; in the second case, you would have two independent variables. However, the second case *might* involve dependent data, which would make things more complex. This would be the case if, as seems likely, people from each store are more similar to each other than they are to people from other stores.

Comment: Is there a test for something like this?   Like is ANOVA applicable here?  Would it make sense to ask if the mean yes rate in one group is different, and or greater than another?

Comment: No, not ANOVA but logistic regression. That is one way to determine if the rates are different.

Comment: Cheers thanks.  Understood, the experiment behind this post involves randomization so the second case I believe would still be independent.  I'm interested in the approaches where instead of 0,1, the outcome is the total spent by a customer.  I think Ill save that for a follow up.  Thanks for your help!